# Is it possible to use Javascript to read local csv file without input from web page?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a web page with php and javascript and now trying to read a csv file from local disk. I've already implemented that if I have a button in the web page and users can click the button, open the file browser and choose the file. However, I don't want the "choose file" button anymore and I want the file to be loaded as soon as the page is opened. So what I intend to do is like following code :

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsText("cgm_data.csv");
 reader.onload = loadHander;

 function loadHandler(event) {
    var csv = event.target.result;
    processData(csv);
}
```

But it seems like I cannot use the reader.readAsText() function in this way. So I want to know is there a way to read local files without input? How should I do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Think about what the world would look like if any website you visited could read arbitrary files off your hard drive without your input.

Comment: If you are only worried about them editing a single set of data, I would use local storage. Keep you UI for loading the initial data. Store that data in local storage. Next time they arrive you can use the local storage version without user interference.

Comment: only if the html file is opened locally as well, not from http

Comment: @Mark_M Good Answer! I didn't think about it from actual users' perspective. You wake me up XD. What I'm trying to do should not be allowed at all.